# Geometry nodes circle point instance looking towards center

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this pretty basic setup

[image]

And I do want them to look (rotate) towards the center. But I only can get the vertices location at the spreadsheet. Maybe I can figured it out if I get the object indices as attribute, but
[since here says](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html) these are the attributes, I couldn't find anything useful, and I couldn't create something works either. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with this node setup:

[image]

Comment: Hrm. Those nodes do not appear to exist in Blender 3.0?

Comment: That’s right. Geometry nodes is heavily under development and the nodes are changing rapidly. I would suggest opening a new question if you want to know how to do it now in 3.0