# Make points rotate so they point towards target object using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to do what is described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CedtNe4CFrk&ab_channel=RyanMaggs

And here: [Geometry nodes circle point instance looking towards center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231892/geometry-nodes-circle-point-instance-looking-towards-center)

The trouble is that both are done in the old version of Geometry nodes. I'd like to do this for Blender 3.1.

I have some cylinders, and I'd like them all to point to the sphere at the center:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The related question that you have linked is already for Blender 3.0 and *Geometry Node Fields*.

The missing part is probably the direction vector.

If you want to let objects point all to a target you need to calculate a vector that points in this direction for each object. The vector is *v = location B* - *location A*.

*location A* is the position of the point/object from the *Position* node and *location B* is the position of the target from the *Object Info* node's *Location*. Use a *Vector Math* node to calculate the vector *v*.

Then use this vector *v* for the *Align Euler to Rotation* node to calculate the needed rotation of the points/objects. That's it.

[image: geo nodes setup]